# Found mold in upstairs crawl space, should I hire a professional?

Tags: mold

I found some mold in my upstairs crawl space. This corner is just inside of the exterior corner of our house. I don't see any visible leaks or any obvious cause. I have some things to remove the visible mold here. But should I be concerned that there is mold or leakage under the dry wall here? Should I be monitoring the moisture levels? Is this something I should contact a mold specialist about?

[image: mold]

Comment: Killing mold is usually easy with household chemicals(bleach is one).  The problem is mold likes moisture/humidity.  So some moisture must be around, a drink spilled, a pet accident, leak from pipes or roof.  To tell it is mold and not dirt, stain, it must be tested.  Off hand from the picture, it looks more like water stain.

Comment: If anything, hire a professional to find the moisture source and mitigate it. In your search for visible leaks, have you seen behind the wet surfaces? Realistically, it sounds like there's some drywalling in your future. Get it over with and cut into that wall to see inside (if you can't see from the other side or something). If you make pretty straight cuts and remove screws, often you can easily reuse the removed drywall.